# IF Statement within Trigger PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers

I have a stored procedure within Oracle that dynamically creates triggers for all of my tables (since they trigger the same stored procedure), by constructing SQL code and executing it with Oracle's PL/SQL EXECUTE command (although I am using SQL Commander for testing). How does one correctly create an if statement within a trigger? Below is my code, which gets syntax error on the line with there IF statement starts.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER "DATABASE"."TABLE_TRIGGER"
AFTER INSERT OR DELETE OR UPDATE ON TABLE
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
v_op VARCHAR2(20);
BEGIN

IF INSERTING THEN
  v_op := 'INSERT';
ELSIF UPDATING THEN
  v_op := 'UPDATE'; 
ELSE 
  v_op := 'DELETE';
END IF;

PKG.STORED_PROC(v_op, ' - MY_COLUMN: ' || :NEW.MY_COLUMN || '', 'MY_TABLE');

END;
```

This is a sample of the code I used to generate the SQL code.

```
PROCEDURE CREATE_TRIGGERS(
            IN_TABLE_OMIT IN VARCHAR2,  -- IN_TABLE_OMIT is a list of tables to not create a trigger on, as CSV
            OUT_RESULT    OUT VARCHAR2) 
AS
    v_table_results SYS_REFCURSOR;
    v_column_results SYS_REFCURSOR;
    v_template_head VARCHAR2(512);
    v_template_body VARCHAR2(512);
    v_template_operation VARCHAR(512);
    v_template_column VARCHAR2(128);
    v_template_data VARCHAR2(1024);
    v_template_foot VARCHAR2(512);
    v_result VARCHAR2(1024);
BEGIN
    -- Create a template for each trigger
    v_template_head := 'CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER "MY_DB"."MY_TABLE_TRIGGER"' || chr(10);
    v_template_head := v_template_head || 'AFTER INSERT OR DELETE OR UPDATE ON MY_TABLE' || chr(10);
    v_template_head := v_template_head || 'FOR EACH ROW' || chr(10) || 'DECLARE' || chr(10) || 'v_op VARCHAR2(20);' || chr(10) || 'BEGIN' || chr(10) || chr(10);
    v_template_operation := 'IF INSERTING THEN v_op := ''INSERT''; ELSIF UPDATING THEN v_op := ''UPDATE''; ELSE v_op := ''DELETE''; END IF;' || chr(10);
    v_template_body := 'MY_DB.STORED_PROC(' || chr(10) || 'v_op,' || chr(10);
    v_template_column := ''' - MY_COLUMN: '' || :NEW.MY_COLUMN || ';
    v_template_foot := '''MY_TABLE'');' || chr(10) || chr(10) || 'END;';
    -- Insert double quotes into template
    -- Loop through each table
    FOR LOOP_TABLE IN (SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM USER_TABLES ORDER BY TABLE_NAME) LOOP
        IF INSTR(IN_TABLE_OMIT, LOOP_TABLE.TABLE_NAME) != 0 OR INSTR('AUDIT_TABLE', LOOP_TABLE.TABLE_NAME) != 0 THEN
            FOR LOOP_COLUMN IN (SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM ALL_TAB_COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = LOOP_TABLE.TABLE_NAME) LOOP
                v_template_data := v_template_data || REPLACE(v_template_column, 'MY_COLUMN', LOOP_COLUMN.COLUMN_NAME);
            END LOOP;
            v_template_head := REPLACE(v_template_head, 'MY_TABLE', LOOP_TABLE.TABLE_NAME);
            v_template_data := v_template_data || ''''',' || chr(10);
            v_template_foot := REPLACE(v_template_foot, 'MY_TABLE', LOOP_TABLE.TABLE_NAME);
            v_result := v_template_head || v_template_operation || v_template_body || v_template_data || v_template_foot;
            v_template_data := '';
            OUT_RESULT := chr(10) || v_result;
        ELSE
            dbms_output.put_line('Searched for ' || LOOP_TABLE.TABLE_NAME || ' in ' || IN_TABLE_OMIT);
        END IF;
    END LOOP;
END;
```

Comment: `ELSEIF` should be `ELSIF`.

Comment: If you break the IF block up over a number of lines the error would be easier to diagnose!

Comment: Dou you need solution in orale or sql server??

Comment: @Tarun Good point - my previous comments assumed Oracle.

Comment: I changed ELSEIF to ELSIF and now receive the error `Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" ` on the first `;` in the IF statement. My apologies for the misplaced tag, I removed it, and I edited the IF statement to be more readable.

Comment: Your trigger looks fine.  Why don't you show us your actual code where you try to create the trigger dynamically?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't paste that code here due to NDA with my company, but it generates them by looping through all tables in the DB using USER_TABLES. I am actually trying to run this code using SQL Commander in DBVisualizer Pro, so I am not running this trigger with the EXECUTE command for testing.

Comment: You don't need to paste the exact code you have if NDA is a concern.  Create a different sample that reproduces your error.  As it is now, if I take the trigger from your post, change the trigger name and table name, and run it in SQL Developer, it works, no errors. Can't reproduce your error.  Have you tried compiling the trigger from your post directly?  Or do you only get the error when you try to create it dynamically from whatever code you are running?

Comment: I've attached a sample of the code I use to generate the trigger. I have tried executing the code from my post directly and dynamically, and I get errors with both.

Comment: looks like you are reproducing the existing audit functionality in Oracle

Comment: @kevinsky can you comment with a link to the existing auditing implementation?

Comment: @vontell see here http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_4007.htm and a useful how to https://oracle-base.com/articles/10g/auditing-10gr2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trigger was successfully created when removing all semi-colons from the generated trigger statement.